# Programa não executa nada quando entra em função

Tags: c, c++

Meu programa executa, mas logo após pedir o valor `prob()` o `.exe` para de funcionar.

Achava que era algum problema de comunicação entre funções por conta da matriz `lattice[][4]` como argumento, mas já procurei, ajeitei e continua acontecendo a mesma coisa. Tenho quase certeza que o problema está na comunicação entre a `main()` e a `label()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int random();
float prob();
int label(float lattice[][4],float);
int i, j;

int random()   /* Sorteia um número entre de 0 a 1 */
{
    float x;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    x = rand()%100+1;
    x = x/100;
    return x;
}

float prob()
{
    float p;
    printf("Probabilidade: ");
    scanf("%f", &p);
    return p;
}

int label(float lattice[][4], float p)
{

for(i=0; i<4 ; i++)
    for(j=0; j<4; i++)
    {
        lattice[i][j] = random();   
    }

for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    for(j=0; j<4; j++)
    {
        if(lattice[i][j] <= p)      
            lattice[i][j] = 1;
        else
            lattice[i][j] = 0;
    }
return 0;
}

int main()
{
     float lattice[4][4];
     float p = prob();
     label(lattice, p);
     system("pause");
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dá algum erro? Edite e coloque os `include`s ou algo mais que o código tenha. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. De ccara eu vi que seu código nem compila.

Comment: não tinha colocado completo, porque o resto tá tudo de boa, o negócio é a main() e a label(). Mas taí, o código completo...

Comment: Rapaz, ta compilando aqui. Mas como disse, o .exe trava depois de pedir a ''Probabilidade: ''...

Comment: Você debugou? Ele trava onde exatamente dentro da função `prob`? Seria no `scanf`? O travamento é consistente (isto é, sempre ocorre)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro é que você está incrementando o segundo laço com a variável errada:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int random() {
    float x;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    x = rand() % 100 + 1;
    x = x / 100;
    return x;
}

float prob() {
    float p;
    printf("Probabilidade: ");
    scanf("%f", &p);
    return p;
}

int label(float lattice[][4], float p) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) lattice[i][j] = random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (lattice[i][j] <= p) lattice[i][j] = 1;
            else lattice[i][j] = 0;
        }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    float lattice[4][4];
    float p = prob();
    label(lattice, p);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/GlT2RX). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/zbmyrosw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Loop/IncrementLoop.c).

Note que eu melhorei um pouco o código. Ainda seria legal usar chaves mesmo onde não precisa. Até mesmo porque já usa em alguns lugares, então mantenha a consistência. Isto é muito importante em programação.

Quando é assim, vai isolando o problema, vai mandando imprimir o valor das variáveis passo a passo ou use uma ferramenta de *debug* que vai mostrando para você. Vendo o programa executar é a forma de achar o problema. Foi basicamente o que eu fiz para achar o problema, por isso eu precisava do código em condições de compilar.

Comment: Bem observado. O AP não devia levar a mal este comentário, mas executar uma depuração ajuda muitíssimo a encontrar esse tipo de problema. Eis uma oportunidade de aprender com os erros. :)

Comment: Poxa, era só isso mesmo ... Valeu, execução em ordem agora.

Comment: Depurar é umas das melhores maneiras de aprender. Escutar os mais experientes é outra :)

Comment: Depuração. Anotado. :D

Comment: :) Outras coisinhas Higor: 1) bem vindo ao SOPT. 2) Se ainda não o fez, faça o [tour] e leia a [help]. Vai te ajudar muito no uso da comunidade.

Comment: Valeu pessoal, site muito útil. ;)